# Ctrl+c terminate process not batch file

Tags: file, batch-file, process, termination

I'm working on a batch file which get remote user process by tasklist. When i press ctrl+c to terminate running process and press Y, it closes the batch file.

But My requirement is to move on specific Label say :start.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> is actually a pre-programmed part of CMD/batch, not  manipulable part of the file. Unless you use a program like batbox in your .bat file, you will not be able to directly manipulate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> command. Even with batbox, I am not sure that you will be able to manipulate the <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd>.

Hope this helps.

Find the batbox program here:[BATBOX download and info](http://www.thebateam.org/2016/06/batbox-awesome-batch-plugin-by.html)

I am not from batbox, just have used the program before with some successes and failures.